# Unable to connect to gmail smtp using zend

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, smtp

I am trying to send email using Zend Smtp.

I have configured everything with zend and with my credential of google.

When I try to send a mail i am getting this error.

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

I am not sure what the mistake i did. Can any one help me out. This is my code.

**IndexController.php**

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
                $mail->addTo('chaitanya5a2@gmail.com', 'Chaitanya Kanuri')
                     ->setFrom('chaitanya@gmail.com', 'Myself')
                     ->setSubject('My Subject')
                     ->setBodyText('Email Body')
                     ->send();

        }
```

**Bootstrap.php**

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initDefaultEmailTransport() {
        $emailConfig = $this->getOption('email');

        $smtpHost = $emailConfig['transportOptionsSmtp']['host'];
        unset($smtpHost);

        $mailTransport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $emailConfig['transportOptionsSmtp']);

        Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($mailTransport);
    }
}
```

**application.ini**

```
email.transportOptionsSmtp.host     = "smtp.gmail.com"
email.transportOptionsSmtp.auth     = "login"
email.transportOptionsSmtp.username = "mygmail@gmail.com"
email.transportOptionsSmtp.password = "mygmailpassword"
email.transportOptionsSmtp.ssl      = "ssl"
email.transportOptionsSmtp.port     = 465
```

Thanks In advance.

Comment: try to check connection in console `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465`